# Why 3 years old questions appear in the weekly newsletter?

Tags: discussion

In this week's newsletter there was a question (very interesting BTW) about [*Why were the Romans unable to conquer Germania?*](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/7345/why-were-the-romans-unable-to-conquer-germania).

When reading the answers, I relized that the question is **three years old**, so are the answers and the "recent activity" is from 22 weeks ago.

What are the criteria for a question to be part of the weekly newsletter?